# Visual Studio 2012 Professional doesn't recognize a class - sometimes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

As far as I can tell, there's no actual problem with my code, but nevertheless Visual Studio doesn't recognize a particular class in my *.h file. It recognizes a struct just before and a class just after - and if I put in an extra

```
class test {
    int foo;
public:
    void bar();
}
```

just before, it finds it (but now it doesn't find `test`.)

To clarify: by recognize, I'm talking about two things: the scope bar at the top of the code window, and the list from expanding FooBar.h. The former insists that the space within the class is still "Global Scope," and the latter lists off all my functions as if they were globals.

This persists across reparses - as noted above, I can fix the problem by adding class `test` and recreate it by removing the dummy class.

IntelliSense still recognizes the class and its methods as belonging to the class, which is decidedly odd...

Actual code follows.

```
//This shows up fine: expanding FooBar.h reveals a sub-list called Update, with
//fields "pE, pEgivenH, E" and methods "Update(...), ~Update(), operator=," and so on.
struct Update {
public:
    double pEgivenH, pE;
    EvidenceID E;

    Update(double, double, EvidenceID);
    ~Update();
    Update &operator=(const Update &rhs);
    int operator==(const Update &rhs) const;
    int operator<(const Update &rhs) const;
}

// Point A

// This doesn't, though. When the cursor is placed within this class, the bar insists
// that it is "global scope", and all methods here show up as global methods under 
// FooBar.h. The problem goes away if I add a class at Point A.
class Hypothesis {
    string hypothesis;
    double currentP;
    double prior;
public: 
    list<Update> history;

    ~Hypothesis();
    Hypothesis &operator=(const Hypothesis &rhs);
    int operator==(const Hypothesis &rhs) const;
    int operator<(const Hypothesis &rhs) const;

    Hypothesis(string, double);
    double updateHypothesis(Update);
    double recalcHypothesis();
    string getHypothesis();
    double getProbability();
}

// This class also shows up fine.
class Action {
    ActionType type;
    Update ubefore, uafter;
    Hypothesis hbefore, hafter;
    EvidenceID ebefore;
public:
    void undo();
    void redo();      
}
```

Comment: Your classes (and structs) need semicolons after the closing brace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing semicolons after each struct/class.

Comment: ... 

*facepalm* Yep, that did it.